# Is there anything I can do about Eclipse getting very slow (and beach balling) when I use Android's XML editor?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, ide

My colleagues and I (all using Juno on Macs) are experiencing the same problem whereby when we're working on Android code, everything is fine UNTIL we open up various xml documents (layouts, manifests, etc). Once we do, there's a limited timespan (usually about 30 minutes) before all sorts of bizarre things start happening.
Namely:

Most actions (like switching between files or saving code or changing perspectives) take multiple seconds (sometimes over a minute) with the beachball twirling.

It starts out slow - initially just delaying actions by a second or two, but pretty rapidly gets so bad that it becomes unusable and requires a restart of Eclipse. (Restarting does fix it).

I'm wondering if this is a known bug and/or if there's a prescribed remedy for it.

Comment: I believe that Juno was described as having performance issues and that Kepler is much better. I went from Indigo straight to Kepler, so can't comment definitively. It might be worth waiting for version L????? Whatever, which I think is out soon.

Comment: The mentioned slowdowns in the initial Juno release were addressed with Juno SR2. Kepler SR2 is what's current now. Tab switching with the XML Editor involved was one of the cases specifically affected; presumably the Android layout editor exposes the same issue since it's based on the same XML editing UI foundations.

Comment: nitind, you should post this as the answer... I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

[Increasing the heap size of Eclipse's JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini), by modifying the `eclipse.ini` file, usually alleviates this problem.

The default values are a little on the low side. We have a pretty big Android project and experienced big slowdowns when compiling, due to excessive GC when Eclipse approaches the memory limit.

For new installations we always use this configuration:

```
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
(...)
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
(...)
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Also, as NickT said, I would recommend updating to Eclipse 4.3.

Comment: sorry... where are you setting this configuration?

Comment: sorry, i posted the wrong link. fixing it in a minute :)